# Javascript grid selection event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm looking for a function which detect when the selection change in my grid table to check to perform a test to check if I have to lock or not a button in my ribbon

Any idea if similar function exists? I've done a search and I found nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it right, that you are looking for an `eventListener`?

I don't really understand what you mean by "when the selection change", but usually there's an event for every change that happens in the `DOM`. I feel like it could be just an `onClick` event on whatever element allows the user to change the selection.

---

Edit: Code snippet to call a function whenever a row that has the class ".row" is clicked.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("row").onclick = function(){
   //put your code here
}
```

Comment: So in fact, I use a grid table
So I'd like to be able to catch an event, each time that the user click on a row

Comment: Alright. I'll add a code snippet for you in my comment above.